# Server-Side Web Framework to use for an Embedded Device

Tags: embedded, lamp

What server-side web language/framework do you recommend for use on an embedded device? The device is similar to a linksys wireless router. Ideally I am looking for a framework that is fast, efficient, and will run well on a device with limited resources (CPU, Memory, etc).

Some initial considerations are PHP, Django, or even mod_perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justin,
    It sounds like your platform has relatively a lot of horsepower.  For this reason, I'd say go with the framework you're most comfortable with.  PHP and mod_perl are plenty fast and efficient.  It really depends on what modules are available for the http server that you're running.

Your question led me to take a peek at the framework that tomato firmware uses for their web interface.  Their server is micro_httpd/mini_httpd with cgi extensions, and the pages are asp.  There is also some javascript thrown in.  Here's a link to [tomato firmware](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) where you can download the source and have a look for yourself.  If your device is similar to a wireless router, you should check out other router firmware projects, such as dd-wrt, openWRT, and sveasoft.

Mateja

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest LUA (http://www.lua.org). Barracuda (http://barracudaserver.com) has a webserver with LUA support, but it's not free.

Answer (score 0):

I working in a team which develop a device like router. for it's web interface, i used [thttpd](http://acme.com/software/thttpd/) and [CGI Wraper](http://www.purplepixie.org/cgi/). programing language was cpp + html + javascript.
i used sqlite for database too.

using cgi c/cpp is the best solution for web interface in embeded device with limited resource.